# when using 'and' to write a compound sentence, what is the role?

Tags: verbs

I'm reading a scientific research paper but not quite sure why some compound sentences are made in certain ways. Here is part of the article:

'Here, we summarize **the roles** of FGF signaling in mouse tooth development and **the ways** FGFs control the stem cells in incisor renewal, **trying** to separate its diﬀerent functions and **highlighting** the crosstalk between FGFs and other signaling pathways. '

I understand that 'the roles' and 'the ways' can be joined with 'and' as well as 'trying' and 'highlighting'. But why they are in the same sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘why they are in the same sentence’? Is there a reason they should not be?

Comment: i mean in order to keep the sentence balanced, shouldn't  the components in the sentence  be consistent in structure? Sorry English is my second language i don't know if i'm explaining it well.